# How to make a tkinter button replace an input prompt on a while loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, user-input

I'm building a python program that connects to my IBM Watson Assistant and runs a 10 question test receiving natural language user input. Searching online, I found some code that runs on a while loop and works perfect on command line.

I started using tkinter to build a GUI, which would include a text box for the prints, an input box for the user's input, and a button get the input and trigger the next question... here is were i'm having a problem.

At the end of the while loop is the prompt for the next question, which calls input() and halts the loop until the user enters the answer to the question displayed on screen, which updates the variable message_input and continues the loop, going through all the questions.

Since I want the user to use only the GUI, I want to replace that input() with the button, making the loop to wait for the button to update the message_input variable with the text on the input box. I've been unable to make it work; defining the variable and removing the input() makes the loop go wild and have found nothing online. How do i do that?

Here's the beginning of the while loop:

```
while message_input['text'] != 'quit':

#Send message to assistant.
response = assistant.message_stateless(
    assistant_id,
    input = message_input,
    context = context
).get_result()
```

Here's the end of the while loop:

```
# Prompt for next round of input.
user_input=input('>>')
message_input = {
    'text': user_input
}
```

Comment: No, ```Label ``` is for printing. A ```text box``` is more inclined towards input, though it can be used for output

Comment: You don't need the while loop in a GUI application.  You can do most of the stuff inside the callback which is executed when the button is clicked.

Comment: The thing is, the while loop is the one that prompts the next questions and interacts with the watson. Since in a beginner level, I cannot change the whole program for the GUI (since the program was built to run on python and the GUI idea came after and i'm building it on top). All i need is a way to replace the final input() with something that halts the loop and waits for the button to be pressed, retrieving the text in the entry widget ("input box").